# Study the following integral: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x \cdot \ln x \cdot \ln^{(2)} x \cdot \ln^{(3)} x ... (\ln^{(k)} x)^s }$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How do I calculate for which values of $s$ the following integral converges?

> $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x \cdot \ln x \cdot \ln^{(2)}  x \cdot \ln^{(3)}  x \cdots (\ln^{(k)} x)^s }$$

$$\ln^{(k)}=\underbrace{\ln(\ln(\ln \cdots (x)))}_{\text{k times}}$$

Comment: Where is this question from? does it converge for $s=1$ and all $k$?

Comment: @nbubis This is a generalization of a question asked in my book.

Comment: If $x<1,$ then $\ln \ln x$ is not defined.

Comment: The left endpoint of the integration range should be something like $e^{e^{\ldots}}$ ($k$ times). Just replace $x$ with $e^{e^{\ldots^{e^u}}}$. This is Cauchy's condensation test in disguise.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

To simply the notation define $\ln_k(x) \equiv \ln\ln\cdots\ln(x)$ where there are $k$ logs on the right hand side. Note that $\ln_k(x)$ is only well defined for $x > 0,1,e,e^e,e^{e^e},\ldots$ for $k=1,2,3,4\ldots$. With this notation your integral can be written

$$\int^\infty\frac{dx}{x\ln_1(x)\ln_2 (x)\cdots \ln_{k-1}(x)(\ln_k(x))^s}$$

From the definition above it follows that $\ln_{k}(x) = \ln(\ln_{k-1}(x))$ so

$$\frac{d\ln_{k}(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{\ln_{k-1}(x)}\frac{d\ln_{k-1}(x)}{dx}$$

Applying this formula $k$ times (using $\ln_1(x) = \ln(x)$) to get

$$\frac{d\ln_k(x)}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\ln_1 (x)}\frac{1}{\ln_2(x)} \cdots \frac{1}{\ln_{k-1}(x)}$$

Now apply the substitution $z=\ln_k(x)$ in your integral , using the result above, to get a much simpler integral for which you can apply your favoritte test to determine the convergence properties.

As mentioned in the comments you should take the lower limit of integration to be larger than $e_k = e^{e^{e^{\ldots e}}}$ in order for all the terms in the integrand to be well defined in the whole region of integration.

Comment: What integral do you get after the substitution?

Comment: @mathlearner What integral did you get?

Comment: How is this defined for $x<1$?

Comment: @nbubis How is what defined for $x<1$? If you mean $\ln_k(x)$ then its not defined for $x\leq 0,1,e,e^e,e^{e^e}\ldots$ for $k=1,2,3,4,5\ldots$ which is why the lower-limit of integration has to be choosen appropriately in order for the integral to be well defined (as mentioned in the last paragraph).

Comment: @Winther - Missed the last paragraph, thanks :)